# Google GIN, GWT, and com.google.inject.Inject(optional=true) not working

Tags: java, gwt, guice, gwtp, gwt-gin

I have a GIN `@Inject` invocation where I use the `optional=true` attribute, but it is simply not honored / not working (and an error is being thrown because my class is not bound, which is true).

I'm using GIN via `.gwt.xml` file like this:

`<extend-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.modules" value="com.example.client.ClientModule" />`

In the above example ClientModule extends `com.google.gwt.inject.client.AbstractGinModule`.

Then I have a class where I `requestStaticInjection` like this:
`requestStaticInjection(Example.class);`

In `Example.java` I have:

```
class Example {
        @com.google.inject.Inject(optional=true)
        protected static SomeUnboundInterface someUnboundInterface = null;
...
}
```

But I get an error during app startup like this:

```
[INFO]             [ERROR] No binding found for com.example.SomeUnboundInterface in com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'gen/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/DesktopGinjectorProvider.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 8: Failed to resolve 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector' via deferred binding
```

Well, that's actually true; My SomeUnboundInterface is indeed not bound; however I was hoping that using the `optional=true` attribute would work.

Please note that the official documentation does not say that for GIN, this attribute is supported. However, [it does say so for GUICE](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_z9rwqdfWAhVMI1AKHU2GDqsQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogle%2Fguice%2Fwiki%2FInjections&usg=AOvVaw3zacLCzeXWXTvesS_E3sgs), so I was hoping it would work for GIN as well.

Do you know of any solution so that I don't get an error if a particular dependency is not bound?

Edit: Forgot to mention version. GWT 2.8.1; GIN 2.1; GWTP 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Optional should works, this example compiles and prints 'null' using GWT 2.8.1 and GIN 2.1.2.

```
static class Foo {
    @Inject(optional = true) Runnable bar;
}

static class MyModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    @Override protected void configure() { bind(Foo.class); }
}

@GinModules(MyModule.class) interface MyGinjector extends Ginjector {
    Foo foo();
}

@Override public void onModuleLoad() {
    L.log(GWT.<MyGinjector>create(MyGinjector.class).foo().bar);
}
```

But if you add a static injection, like you have in your example, it fails. You can either bind it to something or remove the "requestStaticInjection".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand (not very familiar with GIN). 
My code marked with optional is within a library; some clients might choose to provide an implementation which is fine, while some don't which is also fine. Binding to a provider that always returns null won't help because then I can't return the actual instance when I need to.

Comment: Ups, sorry my answer was totally wrong! I have updated it! optional should works on methods and fields, so you should have some other problem. I get confused bc this problem actually happens with @Nullable where you need to explicitly bind it to a null instance using providers.

Comment: So my problem is that static injections don't honor the `optional=true` attribute? Hmm, strange; I'll try it out and see.
I'd very much like to bind it to some default. However, in the code that uses this library, if I do try to bind something else to it, I'd get a "duplicate key" error.